# embed youtube video in TYPO3 from youtube-nocookie.com

Tags: typo3

is there a possibilty to embed a youtube video in TYPO3 8.6 with expanded data protection? That means loading the video not via https://www.youtube.com/embed/.... but from https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/ ...

I am able to load the youtube video in file module with this embed code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/<code>?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But in the frontend the video is embedded with this code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<code>?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply wait for the next TYPO3 8.7 release which is planned for May 22nd. That release will automatically [use the `youtube-nocookie.com` domain for Youtube video embeds](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/7.6.x/Breaking-84843-UseNo-cookieDomainForYoutubeByDefault.html). (Don't be confused by the version here, it's simply missing in the 8.7 branch)

Comment: Thanks! Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Or add

```
 additionalConfig="{no-cookie : '1'}"
```

so it looks like this:

```
<f:media file="{mediaElement}" width="{settings.detail.media.video.width}" additionalConfig="{no-cookie : '1'}" />
```

to the f:media element in FalMediaVideo.html. 
Please be aware that if you dont have those native Typo3 Templates in your own Directory they will get overwritten by the next update ;)